# How do I approach the problem of saving data displayed on a table view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

This a screenshot of my app that collect articles in json format from the newsAPI. I want to implement a feature that saves, deletes and stores the data using CoreData. What is the best way  to approach this problem ?
[Tableview App]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGayE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Read a tutorial about how to add CoreData to your app. And always good to read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata).

Add a single CoreData entity with attributes: image, author, description, date, url, ... (CoreData has a feature to store large(r) data object, like images, in external files. Don't worry about this; just store your images' data inside the entity. Your images won't be very large, won't be very many, and you won't have performance issues.)

Use [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) to populate your table.

Add pull-down-to-refresh/reload logic to the table.

You'd then need to change the data flow of your app: The layer that collects articles will now write to CoreData. The table will now refresh automatically (using `NSFetchedResultsController`) when your data changes. Assuming that you now simple refresh the whole table, with CoreData you need a check to filter out received news items you already have stored (simply to avoid duplicates with every reload).

When filtering away article duplicates, be aware that some fields might be updated. So your logic to find duplicates must be a little more intelligent than just comparing fields of items in CoreData and items received.

Comment: Thanks. Would I have to save the entities as optionals ?